# Using JSON_VALUE in ORACLE PL/SQL to retrieve a nested key

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle10g

I know that this returns the "2":

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"x": "1",  "y": {"a": "2"}}}', '$.y.a') AS value  FROM DUAL;

How do I return "a" from this query:

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"x": "1",  "y": {"a": "2"}}', '????') AS value  FROM DUAL;

This returns null

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"x": "1",  "y": {"a": "2"}}', '$.y') AS value  FROM DUAL;

Comment: `JSON_VALUE` is not supported in Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle 12 or later (which is when JSON support was introduced) then to get the `y` attribute as JSON then you can use:

```sql
SELECT y
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"x": "1", "y": {"a": "2"}}',
         '$'
         COLUMNS
           y VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.y'
       );
```

Which outputs:

| Y |
| --- |
| {"a":"2"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iQHaev0w)

Comment: this is working for me @MT0,  you are a star!  will play around with JSON_TABLE and close ticket shortly